# Passing template parameters to Class#newInstance()

Tags: java, generics, reflection, interface

I have the following class:

```
class Processor<T> {
    void process( T request ) {...}
}
```

I then call the following:

```
Processor<String> p = Processor.class.newInstance();
```

Eclipse complains, as a warning against *Processor.class.newInstance()*:

> "Type safety: The expression of type Processor needs unchecked
>   conversion to conform to Processor< String>"

How do I specify the template parameters to this expression? Something like:

```
Processor<String> p = Processor.class.newInstance<String>();
```

Comment: Forget generics for a minute - what is calling newInstance on the Class object representing an interface supposed to give you?

Comment: `Processor.class.newInstance()` returns a `Processor` (raw type), which you're trying to assign to a parameterized type. You can safely suppress the warning in this case, but don't get into that habit unless you understand what you're doing with generics. :) (And also, the question above is on point.)

Comment: @cppbeginner Sorry, meant to make that a class, not an interface. I updated the question.

Comment: the method `public T newInstance()` is not a generic method, it takes the class generic type `T`, so `<String>newInstance()` won't help

Comment: Well, you can't instantiate an interface, so you've already got a problem...

Comment: Why are you doing this reflectively? Just call the ctor.

Comment: Why not just call `new Processor<>();`? I suppose it's a contrived example,  I would advice using a `Supplier<? extends Processor<String>>` instead if you just need to instantiate it.

Comment: @AndyTurner This is part of a bigger system in which I'm given the java.lang.Class object, not the class identifier itself.

Comment: @yshavit Oddly enough, instantiating an interface that way does seem to work, but either way, I've edited the question since then.

Comment: @Phillip but if that's the case casting to a Processor<String> doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ah I get it now, you *do* have a generic interface, and you are given the class object of some unknown concrete implementation.

Comment: @Phillip "instantiating an interface that way does seem to work" [no, you can't instantiate an interface reflectively](https://ideone.com/jlNHNz).

Comment: What Andy said. By "works" do you mean "compiles" or "compiles and runs without error"? :-)

Comment: @AndyTurner Yep, turns out Eclipse static checking had no problem with it, but instantiating an interface that way threw a runtime NoSuchMethodException against the missing constructor.

Comment: @cppbeginner Right - I'm given the class object of some unknown concrete implementation of Processor.

Comment: Well in that case yshavit had the answer 36 minutes ago. You can just suppress the warning. I'm 99% sure that's safe.

Comment: It still may be better to reconsider the design. Instead of being given a class object and using reflection you should consider JohnVernee's solution above.

Comment: @cppbeginner Not possible. I suppose in the end this is a limitation to the Eclipse linter, and I'll just ignore the warning with a SuppressWarnings annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You have been answered about the reason for warning in the comments, by using Supplier instead, available in Java 8:

```
class Ideone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessorFactory<Processor<String>> pf = 
                     new ProcessorFactory(Processor<String>::new);
        Processor<String> p = pf.build();
        p.process("Ciao!");
    }
}

class Processor<T> {
    void process( T request ) {
        System.out.println(request);
    }
}

class ProcessorFactory<T> {
    private Supplier<T> supplier;

    ProcessorFactory(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    T build() {
        return supplier.get();
    }
}
```

Basically you delegate the generation to en external factory workhorse, which get fed types thru the `Supplier`, `Processor<String>::new` is a reference to the constructor (parameterised).

It is a lot of work for such small benefit, and I am not sure I would do that.

demo here: https://ideone.com/GxQOxG

Answer (score 0):

> I'm given the class object of some unknown concrete implementation of Processor

Instead of trying to do

```
Processor<String> processor = ConcreteProcessor.class.newInstance(); //warning
```

You can simply use the class object you have:

```
Processor<String> processor = classOfConcreteProcessor.newInstance();
```

Depending on the 'bigger system' you mentioned, type information will either be available or not.

If type inference is not possible in your case, you will either

- have to build around it e.g. using factories / supplier
- trust in yourself and suppress the compiler warnings